# Where are "machine certificates" stored on a windows 7 64 bit professional system

Tags: windows-7, vpn

I'm configuring a VPN/IKEv2 connection on my windows 7 workstation (64 bit Professional w/SP1) I plan on using the connection to establish a vpn with my RH Linux 7 server. In the windows configuration "wizard" I have two options: userID & PW and machines certificates. I want to use machine certificates. However I find windows rather obtuse as to what a machine certificate is, AND where are "machine certificates" stored. i.e. which certificate store.

I have generated self-signed certificates using certutil on my Linux 7 system. I have "client" certificate generated for my windows 7 workstation. The question is will windows 7 recognize it as a machine certificate and were to store it using mmc (via certmgr)

Comment: I answered a similar question just follow the steps to add a certificate http://superuser.com/questions/897298/how-is-a-trusted-root-certificate-appearing-in-my-trusted-roots-list/897304#897304